# angularjs ngfacebook batch request

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can anyone who knows how to use the angularjs ngFacebook module help me to perform a facebook batch request? Is it possible to do it with this module?

What I need exactly is to get the user events from facebook, for that I have to do 4 different request:

```
$facebook.api('/me/events/attending').then(function(response) {//code here});
$facebook.api('/me/events/created').then(function(response) {//code here});
$facebook.api('/me/events/maybe').then(function(response) {//code here});
```

I think I could batch this request, I just don't know if it's possible to do using this module.

Also the most tricky part would be that, for each event returned I would need to get the owner, and with the owner.id to get his picture, right now what I do is:

```
$facebook.api('/me/events/attending?fields=owner').then(function(response) {
    //And here I do a "for" into the events to request for each owner picture
});
```

Of course it doesn't seem the best way to do it, but I have searched a lot for the solution and I couldn't make anything work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to request all user events, inluding the owner info:

```
GET /me/events?fields=id,name,owner{id,picture},rsvp_status
```

You can determine the "status" of the event to the user by the `rsvp_status` (attending, maybe, declined, no_reply) field.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event#read
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#fieldexpansion

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. But what about if I need to get like multiple things that cannot go in one query like the one mentioned above? Ex: /me/events/attending?fields... and /me/events/maybe?fields... Do you know how I can do this in javascript with one request?

Comment: The statuses are visible via the rsvp_status as I wrote. If you query /me/events/attending, it will give you a list of attendants. I guess this is not what you want. The query should be fine as-is. If not, what exactly is missing? That's not clear to me...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the batch request protocol that Facebook uses but you could try this module.

https://github.com/jonsamwell/angular-http-batcher

If it doesn't support it add an issue and I'll looking into implementing it.  Disclosure: I created this angular http batching library.

Comment: Well this looks nice, but I am not sure if I can use it to batch the requests to the facebook api, I think they have their only way for batch requests. Which I still didn't manage to run in javascript.